# How to show username if i have 2 tables, user and review

Tags: mysql, sql

i am creating a restaurant review website. in my review table i have a foreign key called user_id and idk how to use it to display the username which is in the user table

[my user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2oSr.png)
[my review table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkYSQ.png)

so my question is how do i display the username from this? what mysql statement do i have to write. I am lost on what to do

Comment: Reading about [joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) could likely help you here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to try and get the review text along with the user name from the corresponding user you can use a join to combine the info for example:

```sql
SELECT u.username, r.review_text
FROM reviews r
LEFT JOIN users u
ON (u.user_id = r.user_id)
```

I assumed the users table is called `users` and reviews table is called `reviews` but update those as necessary each is "aliased" as u and r respectively and then tables are joined

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship between the two tables is mapped out correctly you should be able to run a query to fetch the name of each user. Try to avoid any N+1 query though